# Sharing data between console application and a windows form

Tags: c++, winforms, console-application

I'm writing a program that works primarily in a console, but once in a while, I need to use forms.

I created a windows form and then switched the output to console. After that, I added one more form (Form2) to the project, and now I have code that looks something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> // For std::cout and such
#include "Form1.h"
#include "Form2.h"

using namespace testing_forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 


    /* Instructions Block 1 */

    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());

    /* Instructions Block 2 */

    Application::Run(gcnew Form2());

    /* Instructions Block 3 */

    return 0;
}
```

So, basically, the program runs the 1st Instruction Block, then calls a Form, then runs the 2nd Instruction Block, and so on.

However, this does not allow me to share data between the forms and the console, which, since it is only one program, I really need, such as usernames, integers and such.

The only way I can think of is keeping a text file and writing/reading to/from it from the console and the forms to share the information (I have not tested this), but, to be honest, I don't really like this solution.

So, how can I share data back and forth between a windows form and a console, using (preferably) only variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways - you can use sockets, pipes, message queues, you can store information in a database, you can host a WCF service in the console application etc.

But I won't get into a discussion of which of those is best here. Really, if you are having this problem, then very probably you should make your whole solution a Windows Forms/WPF application. It's a lot easier to pass information between forms of the same application, specially if they can reference each other amongst themselves. They just have to call each other's methods, or access each other's properties, or go for the same static class. All in the same environment, no application boundaries crossed.

If you want to keep the console there, you could have the main form be hidden and open up a separate console app. Then you can feed this console with any relevant text.

Food for thought.

Comment: Uhm... I suppose that would work, yes. If you don't mind me asking, how would I make forms reference each other? Since they are running separately, isn't one form destructed before the next one is created? Unless I'm thinking about this the wrong way...

Comment: C++ is not my *forte* so I can't give you an answer in code. But think about this: `Form` is a class. You can make instances of that. So what happens when a property of your form is also a form? And yes, they can both run at the same time.

Comment: Not quite following. I have 2 different Forms, in two different files, say Form1.h and Form2.h, and in Form1.h I included File2.h. Then, I added a property to Form1, using the line _private: Form2^ NewForm;_  Then, in the event of a button clicked in Form1,  I added the lines _NewForm = gcnew Form2();
   this->Hide();
   NewForm->textBox1->Text=="Open";
   NewForm->ShowDialog();
   this->Show();_

Comment: The lines above hide Form1 while Form2 is active, but I can't do anything with Form1 while Form2 is running, and what I do before is useless. Example: if I do _"NewForm->textBox1->Text=="Open";"_ before showing Form2, the textbox still appears empty.

Comment: Alright, forget what I just said. For some reason I used two equal signs to assign values, which is just plain wrong. With _"NewForm->textBox1->Text="Open";"_, Form2 appears with "Open" written on the text Box. Also, hiding Form2 instead of closing it (i was using function Close() to get out of Form2, instead of function Hide()) allows me to retrieve data from Form2 to Form1.  Thank you very much, I can now share data between Forms. Answer accepted

Comment: The only way one form will block the other is if it is opened as a dialog. Just think about any application that displays multiple forms at the same time... old MSN messenger comes to my mind, each chat was a separate form, all running in the same app. Also I'm always glad to help :)